# Format data in workbook into data frame in R/PYTHON

Tags: python, r

I have unformatted data in Exel that i need to covert into data frame in R

Raw Data:
[image]

which needs to be converted to data frame format in R:

[image]

The Titles like Event name and Time etc., are represented as columns. Is there any way we can do it in R.

Answer (score 0):

If it is saved as an excel workbook, try clicking File > Save As > CSV. Then running the following code to read the file into R as a data frame.

`data <- read.csv("C:/Users/YOURNAME/Desktop/data.csv")`

If this does not load in your data into the manner you'd like (unfortunately, it may not), the solution you are looking for might be much more complicated and would result in changes to the Excel file itself.